# Question on corollary of Hahn-Banach theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hahn-banach-theorem

I read that a corollary of the Hahn-Banach theorem is that if $M$ is a closed linear subspace of $X$ and $x \not \in M$, there is a functional $\phi \in X^*$ with $||\phi||=1$, s.t. 
$$
\phi M = 0, \phi x \neq 0.
$$

In particular, we can form the linear subspace;

$$
Y := [x] + M = \{\lambda x + a : \lambda \in \mathbb{R}, a \in M\},
$$

where $[x]$ denotes the span of $x$.

The desired functional $\phi$ is then:

$$
\phi(\lambda x + a) : = \lambda ||x + M ||
$$

I don't understand...what does $||x + M||$ mean ? since $x$ is a vector while $M$ is a subspace...also how does $ \lambda ||z + M ||=0$ if $z \in M$?

Comment: that should be the norm in the quotient space $X/M$. $x+M$ is a coset

Comment: @CalvinKhor, oh okay, does that mean $||x+W|| = \text{inf}\{||x+w||, w \in W$?.. so that if $z_i \in W$, there is a sequence $z_1,z_2,z_3$ s.t. $||z_i + W|| \rightarrow 0$?

Comment: Yes, thats the norm on the quotient by $W$, but if $z_i\in W$, then $\|z_i + W\| = 0$.

Comment: okay thanks, if you put that as an answer i'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x + M$ is a coset, belonging to the quotient vector spacce $X/M$. This is well defined as long as $M$ is a closed linear subspace of $X$. This is usually given the norm
$$ \|w + M\|_{X/M} := \inf_{m\in M} \|w+m\|_X$$
As part of checking that this is a norm, you'd see that $\|w+M\|=0$ iff $w\in M$. Since $x\notin M$, $\|x+M\|>0$.

Comment: And check that $\phi$ is well-defined. That is, if $a,a'\in M$ and $\lambda x+a=\lambda' x +a'$ then $\lambda=\lambda'$ (and $a=a'$).